# Java 8 Stream: Iterating, Processing and Count

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, side-effects

Is it ok to process and count processed data in such way?

```
long count = userDao.findApprovedWithoutData().parallelStream().filter(u -> {
    Data d = dataDao.findInfoByEmail(u.getEmail());
    boolean ret = false;
    if (d != null) {
        String result = "";
        result += getFieldValue(d::getName, ". \n");
        result += getFieldValue(d::getOrganization, ". \n");
        result += getFieldValue(d::getAddress, ". \n");
        if(!result.isEmpty()) {
            u.setData(d.getInfo());
            userDao.update(u);
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}).count();
```

So, in short: iterate over not complete records, update if data is present and count this number of records?

Comment: you should probably ask this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What does `userDao.update` do?  Is it thread safe?

Comment: @PhilippSander when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman update data in DB. Thread-safe :)

Answer (score 5):

IMHO this is bad code, because:

#### The filter predicate has (quite significant) side effects

Predicates should not have side effects (just like getters shouldn't). It's unexpected, and that makes it bad.

#### The filter predicate is very inefficient

Each execution of the predicate causes a large chain of queries to fire, which makes this code not scaleable.

#### At first glance, the main purpose seems to be getting a count, but really that's a minor (dispensable) bit of info

Good code makes it obvious what is going on (unlike this code)

You should change the code to use a (fairly simple) single update query (that employs a join) and get the count from the "number of rows updated" info in the result from the persistence API.

Comment: what is the strategy/conception to write this code properly (without looking into DB to count result) ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of `process` . I cannot give you a clear `yes or no` because, I think it is hard to conclude without understanding your code and how it is implemented.

You are using **Parallel Stream** and what happens there is Java runtime splits the Stream into sub-streams based on number of available threads in `ForkJoinPool`'s common pool.

When using [parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) you need to be careful for possible side effects:

1. Interference (**Lambda** expression in a stream should not interfere)

> Lambda expressions in stream operations should not interfere.
>   Interference occurs when the source of a stream is modified while a
>   pipeline processes the stream.

2. Statetful Lambda expressions

> Avoid using stateful lambda expressions as parameters in stream
>   operations. A stateful lambda expression is one whose result depends
>   on any state that might change during the execution of a pipeline.

Looking at your question and applying the above points to it.

**Non-interference** > strongly states that Lambda expressions should not interfere with the source of stream (unless stream source is concurrent) during pipeline operation because it can cause:

- Exception (i.e. ConcurrentModificationException)
- Incorrect Answer
- Nonconformant behaviour

With exception of well-behaved streams where the modification takes place during intermediate operation (i.e. filter), read more in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Your Lambda expression does interfere with the source of the stream, which is not advised but, the interference is within **Intermediate** operation and now everything comes down to whether the stream is well-behaved or not. So you might consider re-thinking your lambda expression when it comes to interference. It might also come down to how you update the source of the stream via `userDao.udpate`, which is not clear from your question.

**Stateful Lambda Expression** > Your Lambda expression does not seem to be stateful and that is because the result of Lambda depends on value/s that do not change during the execution of the pipeline. So this does not apply to your case.

I advise you go through the documentation of [Java 8 Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) as well as this [blog](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) which explains Java 8 Stream really well with examples.